# WSDL2Java not producing source client

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm trying to use the WSDL2Java script to create the client classes as per [the user guide](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) but my output is limited to the following and no source is produced:

```
Using AXIS2_HOME:   C:\Users\...\axis2\axis2-1.8.2
Using JAVA_HOME:    C:\Users\...\.jdks\openjdk-20.0.2
```

In a command prompt and running from the axis2\axis2-1.8.2\bin folder I have tried the following command.   (Other variants have been tried but give the same result)

wsdl2java.bat -uri perf.wsdl -p org.companyname -d adb -s

I'm not in a position to share the actual WSDL but have seen [wsdl2java-doesnt-produce-any-output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362458/wsdl2java-doesnt-produce-any-output) and have tried both local and url versions with the same result. For the purposes of testing I have also tried the /axis2/samples/wdsl/perf.wdsl file from the samples folder provided below.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://perf.samples" xmlns:intf="http://perf.samples" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://perf.samples">
<wsdl:types>
    <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://perf.samples" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <element name="inputElement">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="outputElement" type="xsd:string"/>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="handleStringArrayResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="output" element="impl:outputElement"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="handleStringArrayRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="input" element="impl:inputElement"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="PerfPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="handleStringArray" parameterOrder="input">
        <wsdl:input name="handleStringArrayRequest" message="impl:handleStringArrayRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output name="handleStringArrayResponse" message="impl:handleStringArrayResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="PerformanceSoapBinding" type="impl:PerfPortType">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="handleStringArray">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="handleStringArray"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PerfSoapService">
    <wsdl:port name="Performance" binding="impl:PerformanceSoapBinding">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/PerfPortType"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

According to [axis2-generate-a-soap-client-from-wsdl](https://initialcommit.com/blog/axis2-generate-a-soap-client-from-wsdl) I should expect the code to appear in a src folder with I assume the package names within.  This doesn't happen.

There is no error message and the [documentation here](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/reference.html) suggests no verbose flag.

Am I missing something?  Should the output name be a specific format or can it be anything?

Comment: Although the ability to vote anonymously sometimes leads to hasty downvotes, in this case, the reason _might_ have been that you have provided no way for someone else to reproduce the problem. You would have a better chance of an answer if you created a minimal, reproducible example. Post your WSDL, the exact command you’re running (and the base directory), and the output directory structure.

Comment: Thank you @AbhijitSarkar, I have hopefully added more details and hopefully given the ability to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've not tried running your sample, but I noticed that you're using Java 20. A quick check failed to locate a compatibility matrix for Axis, but it won't be unlikely that they didn't support the latest version, especially given that hardly anyone uses SOAP these days. I'd try with Java 17, or even 11.